# StringExpression: Give all pairs of identical characters in the string

Tags: string-manipulation

While going through StringExpression (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression.html), unable to figure out the following:

Give all pairs of identical characters in the string:

Input:

```
StringCases["abbcbccaabbabccaa", x_ ~~ x_]
```

Output:

```
{bb,cc,aa,bb,cc,aa)
```

Why is x_ ~~ x_ used?

Comment: It means a single character x following the same character x.  A good starting point is: https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/42-string-patterns-and-templates.html

Comment: `~~` combines string patterns.